# How to load csv file to GemFire using Spring XD Job

Tags: spring-xd, gemfire

Has anyone one work or guide on how to load csv file to Gemfire database using Spring XD job? Reference or example will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this as a **batch job** then I believe you can use **filejdbc** OOTB job module.

Answer (score 0):

Spring XD doesn't have an OOTB job for raw Gemfire.  As Ilaya points out, if you're using Gemfire's SQL support (via Sqlfire or Gemfire XD) you can use the `filejdbc` job.  Without that support, you'd need to write a custom job that imports the data using Spring Batch's `GemfireItemWriter` support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load csv files into gemfirexd, you can use the build-in system procedure SYSCS_UTIL.IMPORT_DATA_EX().